# How do I turn an arrow to the right, then down, using PlantUML?

Tags: plantuml

How do I turn an arrow to the right, then down, using PlantUML?

Here's an example of what I am trying to do.

```
@startuml
    (*) -right-> "."
    --> Some Activity 
    --> (*)
@enduml
```

[image]
The thing I want to do is shown on the following image:

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Sorry, I don't think you can. I often make a few tweaks in layout with

- left to right direction
- -right->, -left->, -down->
- ordering
- clustering (i.e. box)

But no more than that, because I found that it easily costs more time to manually layout in PlantUML than to draw in a tool like Visio.

If a need a diagram which is very compact, or visually expressive, I use Visio. The other 90%: PlantUML.

What I like most of plantUML is that it creates well readable graphs in a fraction of the time to draw (and in a more maintainable way) (which is why I worked a lot on the PlantUML word add-in, which saves me time in my work).